# Svelte: Out transition in flip animation in grid layout flies off from top left position instead of the item position

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Have a simple `grid layout` in `Svelte` set up which displays a list of items.
A toggle button removes one element from the list, and all other items re-arrange accordingly in animated fashion due the `flip` animation. However, if i'm adding transitions, the `in` works perfectly but the `out` doesn't do what i want. E.g. fade away...

Here the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/49b3731e93704af78df857b2aa1f0c71?version=3.21.0

Note: When the `5` is removed, it doesn't fade away, it flies from the `1` position diagonal to the `5` position.

Any idea what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `transition: all 1s;`. I think this is messing up Svelte inner animations.

Comment: Thats it, Muchas gracias!